# Add a Team Member in a client OS deployed TFS

Tags: tfs, tfs-2017

I installed the Team Foundation server 2017 on my PC. But unable to add another member to a team.

Should I install the Team foundation server on server computer?

Comment: Did you get any error or prompting message when you do the add operation?

Answer (score 0):

TFS can be installed both on a Windows server or **client operating system.**  Note: *TFS 2017 only supports 64-bit operating systems.*

> While TFS supports installation on client OSes, we **don't recommend
>   this except** for evaluation purposes or personal use. TFS installations
>   on client OSes don't support integration with SharePoint products or
>   reporting. The TFS proxy can't be installed on client OSes. If you
>   need to use any of these features, install TFS on a server OS.

More details please refer the [Requirements and compatibility](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/requirements)  doc.

To add another member to a team, for TFS, the first time you add an account you must enter **the full domain name and the alias**.  Take a look at this tutorial: [Add team members](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/work/scale/multiple-teams#add-team-members).